# Create a debian package to install python scripts to /usr/local/bin in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, package, debian, setuptools

I try to create a debian package of a python application as follows:

1. Write a setup.py
2. Generate a debian folder by stddeb
3. Run dpkg-buildpackage -b -rfakeroot -uc to build the debian package

The setup.py is like

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='foo',
      version='1.0.0',
      description='Foo example',
      author='Kuan-Kai Chiu',
      author_email='ntu.kchiu@gmail.com',
      scripts=['src/foo.py']
     )
```

How do I install the foo.py to **/usr/local/bin** instead of being installed to **/usr/bin**? I know there's an option **--install-scripts=/usr/local/bin** while running **python setup.py install**, but I have to debianize my python application and it seems no way to specify the install-scripts prefix.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to install a file in `/usr/local/bin/`, then drop the `setup.py` as it's not really needed. If you are using `dh` in your package (you can see if you are by checking it's being invoked in your `debian/rules` file. If you aren't using it, you should :-), then you'll only have to feed `dh_install` (see its [manpage](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dh_install&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%207.0%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en)) with an `install` file. The syntax of this file is really simple, you have to specify **what** do you want to install, and **where**. You can do this by issuing the following command in the root directory of your package:

```
$ echo "src/foo.py usr/local/bin" > debian/install
```

Now, as you want to install a script under `/usr/local/`, and this is against the Debian policy, one of the `dh_*` tools will fail. This tool is `dh_usrlocal`. The fix is quite simple. We just have to tell `debian/rules` that we don't want to run it, and we can do this by overriding its behavior. This is how your final `debian/rules` should look:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# -*- makefile -*-

%:
    dh $@ 

override_dh_usrlocal:
```

That's it. Run `dpkg-buildpackage` and you should have your fresh new packages in `../`.